# DATE + TIME FIELDS combined to DATETIME not being filtered MS SQL 2008

Tags: sql-server, datetime, filter

I have created a view to display items sold within the last hour, pulled from our point of sale system. The view is being referenced in a SQL script to use DBMAIL, sending a list of items to stores that need to be restocked. The POS system uses separate TKT_DT and TKT_TIM columns, although both are formatted as DATETIM. I understand that since the DATE column always uses 00:00:00 for the time, and the TIME column always uses 12/30/1899, that I can simply ADD the values in both columns to arrive at DATETIME - However, the WHERE filter is not behaving as expected in my query.

```
SELECT     dbo.VI_PS_DOC_LIN.STR_ID
         , dbo.VI_PS_DOC_LIN.ITEM_NO
         , dbo.VI_PS_DOC_LIN.DESCR
         , dbo.VI_PS_DOC_LIN.DIM_1_UPR
         , dbo.VI_PS_DOC_LIN.DIM_2_UPR
         , dbo.VI_PS_DOC_LIN.QTY_SOLD
         , dbo.VI_PS_DOC_HDR.TKT_DAT + dbo.VI_PS_DOC_HDR.TKT_TIM AS TICKETTIME
         , dbo.VI_PS_DOC_HDR.TKT_DAT
         , dbo.VI_PS_DOC_HDR.TKT_TIM
FROM  dbo.VI_PS_DOC_HDR 
FULL OUTER JOIN dbo.VI_PS_DOC_LIN ON dbo.VI_PS_DOC_HDR.DOC_ID = dbo.VI_PS_DOC_LIN.DOC_ID
WHERE (dbo.VI_PS_DOC_HDR.STR_ID <> '3') 
  AND (dbo.VI_PS_DOC_HDR.TKT_DAT + dbo.VI_PS_DOC_HDR.TKT_TIM < DATEADD(minute, - 60, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)) 
  AND (dbo.VI_PS_DOC_HDR.STR_ID <> '99')
```

Data returned is [here](http://pastebin.com/BPkJM04x)

Can anyone suggest something that would limit the results to tickets that have occurred within the last hour?

Note that there are no syntax errors being raised by SSMS, only that the filter is not filtering ANY rows out of the data (except STR_ID 3 and STR_ID 99)

Comment: Before you add a `Date` and `Time` value cast them both `DATETIME` and see how this goes.

Answer (score 0):

Not an answer to your question but you really should learn to use aliases in your queries. As posted your query is very challenging to read. Simply aliasing your tables makes this a LOT easier on the eyes and more supportable.

```
SELECT     l.STR_ID
         , l.ITEM_NO
         , l.DESCR
         , l.DIM_1_UPR
         , l.DIM_2_UPR
         , l.QTY_SOLD
         , h.TKT_DAT + h.TKT_TIM AS TICKETTIME
         , h.TKT_DAT
         , h.TKT_TIM
FROM  dbo.VI_PS_DOC_HDR 
FULL OUTER JOIN dbo.VI_PS_DOC_LIN ON h.DOC_ID = l.DOC_ID
WHERE (h.STR_ID <> '3') 
  AND (h.TKT_DAT + h.TKT_TIM < DATEADD(minute, - 60, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)) 
  AND (h.STR_ID <> '99')
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this....

```
SELECT     dbo.VI_PS_DOC_LIN.STR_ID
     , dbo.VI_PS_DOC_LIN.ITEM_NO
     , dbo.VI_PS_DOC_LIN.DESCR
     , dbo.VI_PS_DOC_LIN.DIM_1_UPR
     , dbo.VI_PS_DOC_LIN.DIM_2_UPR
     , dbo.VI_PS_DOC_LIN.QTY_SOLD
     , dbo.VI_PS_DOC_HDR.TKT_DAT + dbo.VI_PS_DOC_HDR.TKT_TIM AS TICKETTIME
     , dbo.VI_PS_DOC_HDR.TKT_DAT
     , dbo.VI_PS_DOC_HDR.TKT_TIM
FROM  dbo.VI_PS_DOC_HDR 
FULL OUTER JOIN dbo.VI_PS_DOC_LIN ON dbo.VI_PS_DOC_HDR.DOC_ID = dbo.VI_PS_DOC_LIN.DOC_ID
WHERE (dbo.VI_PS_DOC_HDR.STR_ID <> '3')  AND (dbo.VI_PS_DOC_HDR.TKT_DAT = CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE)) AND dbo.VI_PS_DOC_HDR.TKT_TIM <CONVERT(varchar(10), DATEADD(m, - 60, GETDATE()), 108))) AND (dbo.VI_PS_DOC_HDR.STR_ID <> '99')
```